# Access isExplicitNavigationBack from router:navigation:complete event

Tags: aurelia

Aurelia doesn't automatically scroll the browser to the top of the page after navigating to a new route, so I've easily solved this using the `EventAggregator`, listening to the `router:navigation:complete` event inside my main `App` class (`app.js`):

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {EventAggregator} from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@inject(EventAggregator)
export class App {
    constructor (ea) {
        this.ea = ea;

        this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:complete', e => {
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        });
    }
}
```

I recently noticed the `isExplicitNavigationBack` property on the router which would be extremely useful to prevent top scrolling when the user navigates backwards, however, the property is *always* `false`. I've tried with back button as well as `Router.navigateBack()`.

My hope was to simply change my subscription callback to this:

```
if (!e.instruction.router.isExplicitNavigationBack) {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

But unfortunately `isExplicitNavigationBack` is always false - why?

Comment: I think it might be false because the `router:navigation:complete` fires _after_ the routing is complete, and therefore there is no navigation happening at the time. Can you try subscribing to the `router:navigation:processing` event and see if it's true then?

Comment: It's the same inside `processing` unfortunately. Imo it's a little useless if it's _not_ available inside `complete` because that's where I feel like you will want to act on it? I guess if it were available inside `processing` I could store its value somewhere else for later use, but yea, it's always false in there too.

Comment: Looking at the commit here: https://github.com/aurelia/router/pull/453/commits/8a7e8e6219cab37b22b34e06054b3a7b33b3ab4c It sets the variable to `true` when calling `navigateBack()`, and sets it to false in `resolveInstruction()`. Not sure how it will help your case but I'm afraid that's all there is to it, as it was a community PR, so there aren't many docs about it.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's not false inside `processing`. I was 100% sure I tested both yesterday (as I already have both setup) that's why I was so quick on commenting! So thank you :)

Comment: If you put that in an answer I'll give you some credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [commit](https://github.com/aurelia/router/pull/453/commits/8a7e8e6219cab37b22b34e06054b3a7b33b3ab4c) adding the `isExplicitNavigationBack` property you can see that the value is set to `true` when calling `router.navigateBack()` but it's set back to `false` on `resolveInstruction`.

Since you subscribed to the `router:navigation:complete` event, the routing is already complete and therefore the value is set back to `false`. If you subscribe to the `router:navigation:processing` event, it should be `true` if you call `router.navigateBack()`.

```
this.ea.subscribe('router:navigation:processing', e => {
  if (!e.instruction.router.isExplicitNavigationBack) {
    document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
});
```